# How can I reference an instantiated object with only a string representation of its name?

Tags: java, object, reference

Let's say I have an instantiated object:

```
private static ArrayList<Boolean> P1SOLUTION = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
```

There will be similar objects such as P2SOLUTION, P3SOLUTION, etc.
I want the functionality of:

```
Arrays.toString(P1SOLUTION);
```

(Which prints the array as a string).
But let's say all I have is...

```
String myString = "P1" + "SOLUTION";
```

So, when I invalidly write:

```
Arrays.toString(myString);
```

I really want the `String myString` to reference the object `P1SOLUTION` in this example. How can I create this functionality?

Comment: @harryjoy: The original post suggests that there's a program design issue that requires a kludge to fix.  If so, then reflection should not be used where a better design is called for.  It is quite possible that the OP would be better off to use an array of ArrayList or a Map of ArrayList.  I think we need to know more about the problem domain rather than his attempted code solution.

Comment: @oopnoob: why do you think you need this? What overall problem are you trying to solve with this code?

Comment: OP Here. I'm using Java Swing and i have three hard-coded solutions to Nurikabe puzzles. Using a grid layout, the player can solve the puzzle (in north). In the south, there are buttons P1, P2, an P3 that pull up three different puzzles. Next to these buttons is a "check" button that checks the user's input against the hard-coded solution, for that respective puzzle. So I have one button, that needs to have access, or knowledge to, which board is currently on display in the the GUI, so it can check against the hard-coded answer.

Comment: Then you definitely don't need variable variable names. You just need a two-level structure as mentioned already.

Comment: @oopnoob: sounds like you need a simple array and a class field that holds the current index. don't try to kill yourself with complexity when it's not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Store your object instances in a Map. Then reference the instances by name:

Something like this:

```
Map myMap = new HashMap();
myMap.put("P1SOLUTION", new ArrayList<Boolean>());
```

Then get your instance:

```
String myString = "P1" + "SOLUTION";
List myList = myMap.get(myString);
```

Hope this will help you.